# Pre-process model childeren from a template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've got a DetailView to display a Menu (restaurant), with the following structure:

Menu > Courses > Course_Categories > Dishes
i.e. (Theather Menu) > (Starters, Entrees, Desserts) > (Fish Soup, Ribs, etc.)

I want to prefetch the course_categories and dishes, in addition to that I want to set a property on each dish to be used in the template. This property (the price) is dependent on time of day, therefore it's not simple stored as a value on the Dish.

I tried the following:

```
class MenuView(generic.DetailView):

template_name = "cms/detail/menu.html"
model = Menu    

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    pkValue = pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
    menu = Menu.objects.get(id=pkValue)
    courses = menu.courses.all().prefetch_related('course_categories').prefetch_related('dishes')

    for course in courses.all().iterator():
        for course_category in course.course_categories.all().iterator():
            for dish in course_category.dishes.all().iterator():
                dish.price = "0.00"
    return menu
```

When I iterate the data in my template, it shows everything, but no value for the dish.price property. What I think happens is that the related sets are re-retrieved, and therefore my custom set property doesn't show.

Template:

```
        {% for course in menu.courses.iterator %}
            <tr>
                <td><strong>{{ course.name }}</strong></td>
            </tr>
            {% for course_category in course.course_categories.iterator %}
                <tr>
                    <td><em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ course_category.name }}</em></td>
                </tr>
                {% for dish in course_category.dishes.iterator %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ dish.name }} {{ dish.price}}</td>                            
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't really use nbsp for spacing in HTML; define a class in CSS with a value for padding-left and use that class in your td elements.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, it's a rough prototype - so I couldn't bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) which explicitly does not cache the results. When you do `{% for course in menu.courses.iterator %}`, the results are fetched from the database again.

Use simply `.all()` in your view instead of `.all().iterator()`, and stop using .iterator in your template, and you shouldn't have the problem.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it isn't the (full) solution yet. I still can't access any values in the template that I've set in the view. Even though both are now using .all() / .all respectively